# Android- App unexpectedly stopping error and not launching

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When I try to run this on the emulator or on a physical device, the app doesn't launch and a message comes up saying that the app has unexpectedly stopped. There is only 1 class and 1 activity. I have added the required permissions in the manifest. I'm using itelliJ IDE.

Here is the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

Button download , view;
static EditText uID , sID;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;


static String value_sID = sID.getText().toString().trim();
static String value_uID = uID.getText().toString().trim();

private static String file_url = "http://someurl.com"+"/"+value_sID+"/"+value_uID+".pdf"+"/";
String fileName = value_sID+"_"+value_uID;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    download = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Download);
    view = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_View);

    uID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_uID);
    sID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_sID);

    download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/dirs/"+fileName);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Put log plz  for better undrstanding

Comment: show us your log cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the text from your EditText.
But you are doing it in the wrong place.

You need to use the EditText's getText() in onClick of your button.

Also, do not fetch data from UI Elements before initializing. You are fetching the data outside onCreate().

```
sID.getText().toString().trim()
```

The above line should come after:

```
sID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_sID);
```

Please read Android Docs.

Comment: Now the when I give input to the fields and click on download, the progress comes on and goes off in little bit time. When I go to file manager and look in the folder, the file isn't there. How to fix this?

Comment: @Sanchit, that problem is in your AsyncTask's doInBackground(). I would suggest you understand File Handling and Permissions from examples available on the Internet.